# Android WorkManager Periodic task not triggered when app is killed

Tags: android, android-workmanager, periodic-task

My goal is to update my app token(using network request) in every 12 hours whether app is in background or killed so I've used workmanager to solve this. But Periodic task only work when app is in background or open but when I killed the app then periodic task stop to update my app token.

Here is my code:

```
WorkManager mWorkManager;
                    mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context);
                    
                    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                            .build();


                    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicSyncDataWork =
                            new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AccessTokenUpdateWorker.class, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                                    .addTag("ACCESS_TOKEN_SYNC_DATA")
                                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                                    .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                                    // setting a backoff on case the work needs to retry
                                    .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                    .build();
                    mWorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                            "ACCESS_TOKEN_SYNC_DATA",
                            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, //Existing Periodic Work policy
                            periodicSyncDataWork //work request
                    );
```

I'm using workmanager 2.4.0 version

Comment: What do you mean with "when I killed the app"?

If you launch the application from Android Studio, it has a different behaviour than a normal launch:
https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues?hl=ro#ki-force-stop

If your application is "force stopped", the OS removes all the scheduled Jobs and alarms and your periodic worker will not be rescheduled till the user manually opens the app.

Comment: I mean app killed by swipe right from recent app list.

Comment: On which device are you seeing this behaviour?

There are some devices that interpret the removal of an app from the recent app list as a force stop: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: I'm testing Samsung Galaxy M40 but tested Xiaomi devices as well but same result.

Comment: You should be able to check if the jobs are still scheduled after you swipe out the app from the the recent apps list: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging#use_adb_shell_dumpsys_jobscheduler


You can also modify the default logging for WorkManager: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager#3

Also can you check the behaviour of the app in the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my WorkManager settings was correct but Worker class has issue to update the token into server due to context value. You can check my code screenshots. I was assigned wrong context but later fixed it and now code is running perfectly.

[image]

Comment: I've tested Samsung Galaxy M40 device and also emulator it works perfect but few other device maker like Huawei/Xiaomi not works when app killed[swipe from recent list]. Anyone have an universal solution that can work all device maker.

Answer (score 0):

I've h ad the same problem. I solved it by setting "autostart" to "true" and "power saving" to "none" in the app's system page. Try like this.

Answer (score -2):

You have to start it as foreground service.

Everything is explained here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#foreground-service-type

in some cases it is necessary to declare the service in the manifest.

Show the `AccessTokenUpdateWorker.class` code it is more clear.

Comment: AccessTokenUpdateWorker.class is a Extended class of Worker. I don't think service can help. Service will be killed as soon as app is killed.

Comment: Wrong link sorry. Did you check the log to understand if the work end with error or it just doesnt get executed?

Comment: There is no way to check the log as app is killed in order to check the task is running periodically when app is killed. The task periodically run when app is open or background.

Comment: All work request get registered inside a database in you app files. To get work info of all of them you can use workManager.getWorkInfosByTag("ACCESS_TOKEN_SYNC_DATA");  Some of the work constraints migh not be have been matched

Comment: If you check then my only constraints was connected internet but still not trigger.